# Tron Grid 403 forbidden error on a server but not on my local computer

Tags: tron

I'm encoutering an unexpected issue with Tron Grid.

I get a 403 forbidden error when I do the following on a remote server (where an application is hosted):

```
curl --location 'https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/createtransaction' \
--header 'TRON-PRO-API-KEY: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' \
--header 'Accept: '\''application/json, text/plain, */*' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data '{"to_address":"413df772b82d32369858f2622cca0948b5e351d68c","owner_address":"417d663370f99806b1830d13b2a1b26f710473c6cd","amount":29000000}'
```

On the server it worked few days ago.

However, when I do exactly the same in a local computer. The request is successfull.

The rate limit have not been reached for the provided TRON-PRO-API-KEY.

I suspect a kind of blacklist of the server's IP but not sure.

How can I fix the issue ?

Thank you,